# Clarification on the physical mechanism in an exercise question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Following is a question from Rindler

> Prove that at any instant there is just one plane in $S$ on which the clocks of $S$ agree with the clocks of $S'$, and that this plane moves with velocity $\frac{c^2}{v}(1 − 1/\gamma)$.

I somehow managed to prove whatever is required, but I have no idea what I have done or why.

Here is what I did
$$ t'=(t-\frac{vx}{c^2})\gamma$$
Now for some reason I wrote t'=t, which I don't know why (and for which I need an explanation), to get
$$\frac{t}{\gamma}=t-\frac{vx}{c^2}$$
That gives me
$$\frac{x}{t}=\frac{c^2}{v}(1 − 1/\gamma)$$
As $\frac{x}{t}$ is the speed of the plane, this proves what is being asked (this again is my assumption that $\frac{x}{t}$ is the speed of the plane and I need an explanation if this is correct or not. Also I don't have any idea what is $v$ here.

Comment: I think you must have made a typo here, you write "there is just one plane in S on which the clocks of S agree with the clocks of S".

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I just copied the question from the PDF, checked it once more as well, this is what was written there

Comment: This appears as Problem 2.7 in the 2nd edition of Rindler's *Relativity: Special, General and Cosmological*, in which the second "$S$" in this question appears as an $S'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the third S in the question should be an S'.   Something lost in the cut and paste.

$v$ is the relative speed of the two frames, S and S'

All that, and definitions of $\beta$ and $\gamma$, is pretty standard notation in relativity problems like this.

Setting $t'=t$ as you correctly did is just saying *the clocks in S agree with the clocks in S'*

The answer you correctly derive is saying that in general a clock in S at $(x,y,z,t)$ disagrees with the clock at the same spacetime point but viewed in S'.
At small $x$, $t'$ is bigger than $t$; at large $x$, $t'$ is smaller.  The boundary, where they agree, is at $x={c^2 \over v}(1-1/\gamma) t$. So that boundary starts at the $x=0$ plane and increases with $t$.

Comment: Yeah but what exactly is $v$ here

Comment: If, for example, a train is moving through a station, with the S frame set up on a train and the S' frame set up on the station platform, then $v$ is the speed of the train relative to the platform (and also the speed of the platform relative to the train).

Comment: in that case why wouldn't the speed of S' be $v$?